# jScrollPane initial setup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

I don't understand the documentations at jScrollPane at all. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples

They give an example as such to start (Assuming there is text in this class):

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

That does not work at all. Instead, I have to do something like this

HTML:

```
<div id="dummy">Put few paragraphs here for overflow</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="oflow"></div>
</div>
<a href="" id="get">Get text</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#get").click(function() {
        $("#oflow").html($("#dummy").text());
        $("#wrapper").jScrollPane();
    });
});
```

So... Question: If I turn it into a function and use it in this way for loading text with `$.get()` and inserting new content with `$(element).html(e.responseText)`, jScrollPane only works for on first click on any content loading.

I've ran a sample at jsFiddle and can't get it to work properly. The jscrollpane should go away when a large amount of text is replace by less content. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/Hq5hC/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user jquery live as it binds to the elements which can come in future

this is problem in your code

```
$("a").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

this is killing the event..

http://api.jquery.com/live/

example

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

Comment: nope. if i change it to live, it just doesn't even execute loading the text at all. I think i just need to find an alternative. jScrollPane seems to be buggy. Every once in a while it works, then it don't. Just now i went back to the jsfiddle, and changed from click to live, didn't work, changed  back to click, and works properly. changed to live, no work, back to live, not work again either.

Comment: now it works with live and click lol. strange thing it is. Any idea for better overflow scrolling styles?

Comment: This one dont't work: http://jsfiddle.net/robx/Hq5hC/17/    This one does: http://jsfiddle.net/robx/zbTsU/13/  What's the difference is only live and click. You'd expect both to work or live to do future binding...

Comment: @robx , as you are adding at the run time , you need live , normal bind works for the elments which gets loaded on load of the page.

Comment: @I don't think there are bugs with jscrollPane , it just need a divid or class and wraps scrolls bars around it.

Comment: but why does live not even load the content when clicked? Or is it just my machine lol.

Comment: use firebug and start debuging by having breakpoints , otherwise you might be having problem with id or class

Comment: have you looked and tried the two jsfiddle i just put a few comments up? does the live work for you? Also if you try to move the $("#wrapper").jScrollPane() above the click event, it will just break the whole script.

Comment: found the problem , this is the problem in your code $("a").click(function() {
    return false;
});  as you generic a click return false it is killing the events.

Comment: okay so if i remove that then the link wants to open up a page. How do i go about stopping a links default behavior if that is taken away? Edit. never mind. Duh me, i could just return false the live function lol.

Comment: @robx , do a return false inside your live click for ..large that should do it.

Comment: That still remains the question as to if I call the $("#wrapper").jScrollPane() before the click events, then seems like nothing happens.

Comment: Okay, not that it doesn't work. It seems to be an issue with the jScrollPane CSS and it's inline styling. I'm chunking this one. Too much headache to deal with. Thanks for help and time.